# Signature test failed at Truffle js

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, signature, truffle-test, ethereumjs-tx

I'm  trying to test validAddress function from my contract ValidationUser, using truffle and test with JS. I checked the V value from the signature and its 27,28 so it is not the problem.
Also, I have the code inside Unity side that works ok with this function!
But inside the test it's failed on: addressCheck != to the sender address - the owner. 
Any suggestions how to fix the test?

ValidationUser.sol:

```
constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

function validAddress(
    int256 theMsg,
    uint8 v,
    bytes32 r,
    bytes32 s
) public payable returns (uint8) {
    bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, owner, theMsg));
    address addressCheck = ecrecover(hash, v, r, s);
    if (addressCheck != owner) {
        revert(addressToString(addressCheck));
        //  return v;
    }
}
```

ValidationUser.js:

```
it('should return valid result from validAddress function', async function () {

    var EthUtil = require('ethereumjs-util');
    const messageToSign = web3.utils.toBN(12);
    //privateKey ot the owner - accounts[0]:
    const privateKey = "b25421d6dabd6e9119c45c4daf4ca4f8f86bd6761cc20c095906073da7c02471";
    var hash = EthUtil.hashPersonalMessage(new Buffer(accounts[2] + accounts[0] + EthUtil.intToHex(messageToSign)));
    var signature = EthUtil.ecsign(hash, new Buffer(privateKey, 'hex'));
    var signatureRPC = EthUtil.toRpcSig(signature.v, signature.r, signature.s)
    console.log(signatureRPC);

    const contract = await ValidationUserContract.deployed();
    const owner = await contract.getOwner();
    const theMsg = await contract.validAddress.call(messageToSign,
        signature.v,
        signature.r,
        signature.s, {
            from: accounts[2]
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself!!

ValidationUser.sol:

```
function validAddress(
    int256 theMsg,
    uint8 v,
    bytes32 r,
    bytes32 s
) public payable returns (bool) {
    bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, owner, theMsg));
    return isSigned(owner, hash, v, r, s);
}


function isSigned(
    address _addr,
    bytes32 msgHash,
    uint8 v,
    bytes32 r,
    bytes32 s
) public pure returns (bool) {
    return ecrecover(msgHash, v, r, s) == _addr;
}
```

ValidationUser.js:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    contract = await ValidationUserContract.deployed();
});

function toHex(str) {
    var hex = ''
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        hex += '' + str.charCodeAt(i).toString(16)
    }
    return hex;
}

it('should return valid result from isSigned function', async function () {
    var str = 'msg';
    let signature = await web3.eth.sign('0x' + toHex(str), accounts[2])
    signature = signature.substr(2); //remove 0x
    const r = '0x' + signature.slice(0, 64);
    const s = '0x' + signature.slice(64, 128);
    const v = '0x' + signature.slice(128, 130);
    const v_decimal = web3.utils.toDecimal(v)
    let fixed_msg = `\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n${3}${str}`
    let fixed_msg_sha = web3.utils.sha3(fixed_msg)
    const theMsg = await contract.isSigned.call(accounts[0], fixed_msg_sha, v_decimal, r, s, {
        from: accounts[0]
    });
});


it('should return valid result from validAddress function', async function () {
    var str = 12;
    let signature = await web3.eth.sign(str, accounts[2])
    signature = signature.substr(2); //remove 0x
    const r = '0x' + signature.slice(0, 64);
    const s = '0x' + signature.slice(64, 128);
    const v = '0x' + signature.slice(128, 130);
    const v_decimal = web3.utils.toDecimal(v)
    let fixed_msg = `\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n${2}${str}`
    let fixed_msg_sha = web3.utils.sha3(fixed_msg)
    const theMsg = await contract.validAddress.call(fixed_msg_sha, v_decimal, r, s, {
        from: accounts[0]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check

- Does the message's hash match the signed one? The concatenation in a buffer looks wrong.
- Does signed message include "Ethereum signed.." prefix? ECRecover doesn't prepend it.
- Make sure `v` parameter is either 27 or 28, some libraries return 0 or 1 instead.

Comment: what "Ethereum signed.." prefix means? do you have example? V value from the signature and its 27,28 so it is not the problem.. how you suggest to concatenation?

Comment: @Dorel  Some api's like `eth.sign` will prepend a prefix before signing, other like `personal.sign` will not. If `ecsign` used the prefix take a look at [OpenZeppelin contracts](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/cryptography/ECDSA.sol#L78-L82) how to prepend it. I'd guess that `accounts[]` starts with `0x` you should not include those when hashing. Also the result should be hexadecimal and have to use 'hex' parameter with Buffer after concatenation.